# How to pattern match a String in a struct against a literal

Tags: string, struct, rust, match

In my code below I find that the code in `match_num_works()` has a certain elegance. I would like to write a `String` match with a similar formulation but cannot get it to work. I end up with `match_text_works()` which is less elegant.

```
struct FooNum {
    number: i32,
}

// Elegant
fn match_num_works(foo_num: &FooNum) {
    match foo_num {
        &FooNum { number: 1 } => (),
        _ => (),
    }
}

struct FooText {
    text: String,
}

// Clunky
fn match_text_works(foo_text: &FooText) {
    match foo_text {
        &FooText { ref text } => {
            if text == "pattern" {
            } else {
            }
        }
    }
}

// Possible?
fn match_text_fails(foo_text: &FooText) {
    match foo_text {
        &FooText { text: "pattern" } => (),
        _ => (),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Its probably not "elegant" or any nicer.. but one option is to move the conditional into the match expression:

```
match foo_text {
    &FooText { ref text } if text == "pattern" => (),
    _ => ()
}
```

[Working sample: Playpen link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=struct%20FooText%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20text%3A%20String%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20match_text_fails(foo_text%3A%20%26FooText)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20match%20foo_text%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26FooText%20%7B%20ref%20text%20%7D%20if%20text%20%3D%3D%20%22pattern%22%20%3D%3E%20println!(%22Matches%3A%20%27%7B%7D%27%22%2C%20text)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_%20%3D%3E%20()%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20foo%20%3D%20FooText%20%7B%20text%3A%22pattern%22.to_string()%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20match_text_fails(%26foo)%3B%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0).

Comment: Thanks! That will do.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your desired pattern would actually work with a `&str`. You can't directly pattern match a `String` because it's a more complex value that includes an unexposed internal buffer.

```
struct FooText<'a> {
    text: &'a str,
    _other: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let foo = FooText { text: "foo", _other: 5 };
    match foo {
        FooText { text: "foo", .. } => println!("Match!"),
        _ => println!("No match"),
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d30f449ef8dd16ea02c587116b6fd7cc&version=stable&backtrace=1)